# Finding the combination from an array of numbers that gives the required coefficient

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Please recommend the optimal algorithm or solution for such a task:

There are several arrays with fractional numbers

```
a = [1.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 7, 10, ...(up to 100 numbers)]
b = [5, 6, 8, 14, ...]
c = [1, 2, 4, 6.25, 8.15 ...] (up to 7 arrays)
```

Arrays can be of arbitrary length and contain a different count of numbers.

It is required to select one number from each array in such a way that their product was into a given range.

For example data required product should be between 40 and 50.
Solution can be:

1. a[2] * b[2] * c[1] = 3 * 8 * 2 = 48
2. a[0] * b[3] * c[1] = 1.5 * 14 * 2 = 42

If there can be several solutions (different combinations), then how can you find them all in the optimal way?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** ideas / findings / code.

Comment: What is the real problem behind this task? May there is better way to solve the initial problem. Also, it could help to add some constraints on the data, like `number >= 1` and so on.

Comment: Since you didn't post your brute force implementation, we can only guess if you considered any optimizations in it. Here some fist thoughts: Since the value seams to be ordered (per array), you can eliminate a lot of cases early. Also considering the smallest value per array and the largest can be used to skip a lot of cases. ..: (Also extracting a factor from each array to ensure that each array contains 1 can be useful)

Comment: @YD1m In the question, all the input arrays you provided were sorted. *Will the input arrays be sorted always?*

Comment: @YD1m is only one solution for each range required or must ALL possible solutions be counted or displayed?

Comment: @Surt Your question seems to be answered by the phrase, *If there can be several solutions (different combinations), then how can you find them all in the optimal way?*

Comment: Do you need to explicitly enumerate all combinations i.e find all tuples of indices within each array whose product lies in the range? If so we can't really do much better than a brute-force search. For example, if our range is between 1 and 2 inclusive and and we have two arrays of size 100 each containing only 1s, we need to list our every single pair... Perhaps you need to edit what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: @wLui155 The worst case, yes.  The average case we can do better though.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but barely.  This will require combining pairs of things over and over again using a variety of strategies.

First of all if you have 2 arrays of no more than 100 things, you can create an array of all pairs, sorted by sum either ascending or descending, and it only has 10,000 things in it.

Next, we can use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) to implement a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

With a priority queue, we can combine 2 ordered arrays of size at most 10,000 to stream out the sums in either ascending or descending order while not keeping track of more than 10,000 things.  How?  First we create a data structure like this:

```
Create priority queue
For every entry a of array A:
    Put (a, B[0], 0) into our queue using the product as a priority
return a data structure which contains B and the priority queue
```

And now we can get values out like this:

```
If the priority queue is empty:
    We're done
else:
    Take the first element of the queue
    if not at the end of B:
        insert (a, b[next_index], next_index) into the queue
    return that first element
```

And we can peek at them by just looking at the first element of the queue without touching the data structure.

This strategy can stream through 2 arrays of size 10,000 with total work just a few billion operations.

OK, so now we can arrange to always have 7 arrays. (Some may simply be a trivial `[1]`.)  We can start as follows with the brute force strategy.

```
Combine the first 2 ascending.
Combine the second 2 ascending.
Combine the third 2 descending.
Arrange the last descending.
```

Next we can use the priority queue merge strategy as follows:

```
Combine (first 2) with (second 2) ascending
Combine (third 2) with last descending
```

We just need the generators at the moment.

Now our strategy will look like this:

```
For each combination (in ascending order) from first 4:
    For each combination that lands in window from last 3:
        emit final combination
```

But how do we do the window?  Well, as the combination from the first 4 goes up, the window that the last 3 has to fall in goes down.  So adjusting the window looks like this:

```
while there is a next value and next value is large enough to fit in the window:
    Extract next value
    Add next value to end of window
while first value is too large for the window:
    remove first value from the window
```

(Variable sized arrays, such as Python's `List`, can do both these operations in amortized `O(1)` each.)

So our actual way to finish is:

```
For each combination (in ascending order) from first 4:
    adjust entries in window from last 3
    For each in window from last 3:
        emit final combination
```

This has a fixed overhead of a few billion operations plus `O(number of answers)` to actually emit the combinations.  This includes a number of data structures with around 10k items, plus a window whose maximum size is 1 million items for a maximum memory usage of a few hundred MB.